# Git: How do I merge the remote branch of another developer's with my master branch?

Tags: git

I am currently a graduate student trying to do some research using a large software project that the group I am a part of is developing. However, the specific piece of the project that I need was developed by another student who has since graduated, and has yet to merge his code with the main codebase.

I really need to get my hands on this code, but it's been several weeks since I talked to him, and he hasn't initiated a merge request yet. Is there a way for me to remotely merge his branch with my master branch?

So far, I have tried to bring this up during a group meeting. I'm not sure if I communicated the situation in the most exact or effective way because I was trying to be diplomatic, but the impression I was left with is there's a way for me to get a hold of the changes he's made without needing to clone the main codebase after he's merged with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add their repo as a new remote. Fetch it. Merge their branch.

There might be a way to do this on Github, but it's easy to do manually.

Add them to your local repository as a new remote repository. `git remote add <name> <url>` You can name it whatever you want, perhaps after their username.

Fetch it. `git fetch <name>`. This won't affect your work at all. All of their branches will be prefixed with their remote name; their main branch will be `<name>/main`.

And merge it like any other branch. Alternatively, if you just need certain commits, you can [cherry pick](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick) them.

Since the branch is a little old, you might want to first update it. Make a new local branch from their remote branch: `git branch <branch> <name>/<branch>`. Then merge any updates into that new branch. Test it. Do any necessary fixes. Then merge the branch.

Comment: Thank you so much, one followup question: what should the <url> field be? 

Is it just the filepath to the corresponding .git directory on their machine?

Comment: @Ashamandarei: The `<URL>`  is the address/location of the repository you want to add. Use one you have access to. This _can_ be via a file-share but also other transports like SSH or HTTPS can work, too. Compare with https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes and with more detail on the different protocols (with more URL examples): https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: @Ashamandarei Its the same URL as you'd use to clone their repository. It can also be a file path if you've already cloned their repository.